# "Though, Palmares is no more thousands of other quilombos persist to this day."

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw this sentence in Youtube.
*"Though, Palmares is no more thousands of other quilombos persist to this day."*
(The source: https://youtu.be/5ckmXwx2n88?t=284)

I can't understand the structure of this sentence.
How can one sentence have two verbs(is, persist) without any connectors like conjunctions or relativizers?

Comment: The comma is in the wrong place. "Though Palmares is no more, thousands of other quilombos persist to this day".  Bad subtitles!

Comment: The comma is misplaced in the subtitles; it should come after _more_. 'Even though Palmares no longer exists, thousands of other _quilombos_  still remain.'

Comment: Thank you all! I thought "though" is an adverb like "~~~, though(=however)." cuz of the comma. If I had heard the sentence first without subtitles, I would've understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments by [@BillyKerr](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/68154) and [@KateBunting](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/104866), the comma is simply in the wrong place, and that part of the video should instead be transcribed as "*Though Palmares is no more, thousands of other quilombos persist to this day.*", which could (possibly) be rephrased more simply (to explain what it means) as: "Palmares no longer exists, but thousands of other quilombos still do."